# PostgreSQL xpath missing parent data

Tags: xml, postgresql

I am trying to select data from an XML structure where 2 fields are in the parent and the rest in multiple child entries.

```
SELECT  
                CAST(unnest(xpath('//LINEINFO/SONUMB/text()', node::xml))AS TEXT)   AS salesordernumber,
                CAST(unnest(xpath('//LINEINFO/LINPOS/text()', node::xml))AS TEXT)   AS linenumber,
                CAST(unnest(xpath('//SNUMBINFO/SNUMB/text()', node::xml)) AS TEXT)  AS serialnumber,
                CAST(unnest(xpath('//SNUMBINFO/SQTY/text()', node::xml)) AS TEXT)   AS quantity,
                CAST(unnest(xpath('//SNUMBINFO/STATUS/text()', node::xml)) AS TEXT) AS status,
                CAST(unnest(xpath('//SNUMBINFO/WEIGHT/text()', node::xml)) AS TEXT) AS weight,
                CAST(unnest(xpath('//SNUMBINFO/UPDATE/text()', node::xml)) AS TEXT) AS updatevalue
        FROM    (
                    SELECT  '<root>
    <LINEINFO>
        <SONUMB>123123123</SONUMB>
        <LINPOS>10</LINPOS>
        <SNUMBINFO>
            <STATUS>Normal</STATUS>
            <SQTY>1</SQTY>
            <SNUMB>47</SNUMB>
            <UPDATE>no</UPDATE>
            <WEIGHT>0</WEIGHT>
        </SNUMBINFO>
        <SNUMBINFO>
            <STATUS>Normal</STATUS>
            <SQTY>1</SQTY>
            <SNUMB>48</SNUMB>
            <UPDATE>no</UPDATE>
            <WEIGHT>0</WEIGHT>
        </SNUMBINFO>
        <SNUMBINFO>
            <STATUS>Normal</STATUS>
            <SQTY>1</SQTY>
            <SNUMB>49</SNUMB>
            <UPDATE>no</UPDATE>
            <WEIGHT>0</WEIGHT>
        </SNUMBINFO>
        <SNUMBINFO>
            <STATUS>Normal</STATUS>
            <SQTY>1</SQTY>
            <SNUMB>50</SNUMB>
            <UPDATE>no</UPDATE>
            <WEIGHT>0</WEIGHT>
        </SNUMBINFO>
        <SNUMBINFO>
            <STATUS>Normal</STATUS>
            <SQTY>1</SQTY>
            <SNUMB>51</SNUMB>
            <UPDATE>no</UPDATE>
            <WEIGHT>0</WEIGHT>
        </SNUMBINFO>
    </LINEINFO>
</root>' as node
                ) tbl_productionorder
```

the problem I have is the parent values only appears on the first output record, is there a way to get the values repeated on all lines.

| salesordernumber | linenumber | serialnumber | quantity | status | weight | updatevalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123123123 | 10 | 47 | 1 | Normal | 0 | no |
| *null* | *null* | 48 | 1 | Normal | 0 | no |
| *null* | *null* | 49 | 1 | Normal | 0 | no |
| *null* | *null* | 50 | 1 | Normal | 0 | no |
| *null* | *null* | 51 | 1 | Normal | 0 | no |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution based on `XMLTABLE()`.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Pq5_izhz)

**Postres SQL**

```
WITH rs AS
(
  SELECT XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT '<root>
    <LINEINFO>
        <SONUMB>123123123</SONUMB>
        <LINPOS>10</LINPOS>
        <SNUMBINFO>
            <STATUS>Normal</STATUS>
            <SQTY>1</SQTY>
            <SNUMB>47</SNUMB>
            <UPDATE>no</UPDATE>
            <WEIGHT>0</WEIGHT>
        </SNUMBINFO>
        <SNUMBINFO>
            <STATUS>Normal</STATUS>
            <SQTY>1</SQTY>
            <SNUMB>48</SNUMB>
            <UPDATE>no</UPDATE>
            <WEIGHT>0</WEIGHT>
        </SNUMBINFO>
        <SNUMBINFO>
            <STATUS>Normal</STATUS>
            <SQTY>1</SQTY>
            <SNUMB>49</SNUMB>
            <UPDATE>no</UPDATE>
            <WEIGHT>0</WEIGHT>
        </SNUMBINFO>
        <SNUMBINFO>
            <STATUS>Normal</STATUS>
            <SQTY>1</SQTY>
            <SNUMB>50</SNUMB>
            <UPDATE>no</UPDATE>
            <WEIGHT>0</WEIGHT>
        </SNUMBINFO>
        <SNUMBINFO>
            <STATUS>Normal</STATUS>
            <SQTY>1</SQTY>
            <SNUMB>51</SNUMB>
            <UPDATE>no</UPDATE>
            <WEIGHT>0</WEIGHT>
        </SNUMBINFO>
    </LINEINFO>
</root>') as x
)
select t.*
from rs
cross join XMLTABLE(
      '/root/LINEINFO/SNUMBINFO'
       PASSING rs.x
       COLUMNS 
           salesordernumber varchar(64) PATH '../SONUMB',
           linenumber       int         PATH '../LINPOS',
           serialnumber     varchar(10) PATH 'SNUMB',
           quantity         int         PATH 'SQTY',
           status           varchar(10) PATH 'STATUS',
           weight           varchar(10) PATH 'WEIGHT',
           updatevalue      varchar(10) PATH 'UPDATE'
) as t;
```

**Output**

| salesordernumber | linenumber | serialnumber | quantity | status | weight | updatevalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123123123 | 10 | 47 | 1 | Normal | 0 | no |
| 123123123 | 10 | 48 | 1 | Normal | 0 | no |
| 123123123 | 10 | 49 | 1 | Normal | 0 | no |
| 123123123 | 10 | 50 | 1 | Normal | 0 | no |
| 123123123 | 10 | 51 | 1 | Normal | 0 | no |

Comment: thanks, that works great. It seems to be an incompatibility between my old DB version and the new one.